# C - Check If All Values of Struct Array Return Same Values

Tags: c, struct

I want to check if all values of a struct array hold the same value for the purpose of hiding "deleted" entries in the struct array.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct spawnedObject {
    Hash objHash;
    Object obj;
    char* displayname;

    int invisibility;
    Vector3 position;

    int deleted; // 1=deleted and hidden, 0=should be listed and available
};
```

And I want to check if `deleted` is true for all entries in the struct. When they're all true, have the `else` display the empty text.

I have tried looping all `deleted` values and increasing an int when a value is set to `1` like so:

```
void objectManagerMenu() {
    objectVar = 0;
    int inc = 0; //store deleted entries count

    // loop through all entries. if entry deleted, increase.
    for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) {
        if(spawnedObjects[i].deleted) inc++;
    }

    // check if there either are no entries, or if theyre hidden. if all stored entries are hidden, fallback to else. this is where it goes wrong.
    // problem: does not seem to fallback to else.
    if(objectCount != 0 || objectCount != inc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) {
            if(!spawnedObjects[i].deleted) { // remove hidden items from list
                char buffer[150];
                sprintf(buffer, "[ %i ] %s", i, spawnedObjects[i].displayname);

                menu.option(buffer).call(objectItemVar, i).submenu(objectItemMenu);
            }
        }
    } else {
        menu.option("Empty");
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to work as nothing is being displayed.

Does anybody have a suggestion how I can do this a smarter way?

Comment: Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Please have some patience as some people like me just started reading

Comment: Its really hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do with the code given and your few sentences. Comment your code to explain some variables, like menu or inc. Also is the || in the if statement really what you want to do? By my guess you might want to use && instead of ||

Comment: @RIJIK Sorry. The approach is to basically "delete" entries in a *menu*. Once an entry is deleted, `deleted` in the struct will be set to `1` and the entry will be hidden from the list. Works fine, but when everything is "deleted" (set all entries to `1` in `deleted`) it displays nothing. I want to show the "Empty" text when there are entries in the array struct but when they're **all** set to `1` in `deleted`. Hope I explained this well.

Comment: Have added comments to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your || in the if statement like stated int the comment.

```
objectCount != 0
```

most likely returns true

```
objectCount != inc
```

returns false, because the menu is empty (in your current scenario which you are tryining to test)
by that the `if` statement will always be true (if your object count is bigger then 0) and thus `else` is never executed.
change the `||` to `&&`

Why
 `||` returns true if at least one of the statements gives true.
&& returns true **only when both** are true and that is what you want

Comment: Ah that seemed to fix it. Weird, I thought I tried that aswell. I guess not, thanks!